# Add a date to the abbreviated label (IOS)

Tags: swift3

I have got label with big text. This text is compressed. For example:

Text: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

Label: "abcdef..."

I want add date to the end shrinking text:

True label: "abcdef... 1:12:5"

How I can add string to the end shrinking label?

Comment: Append date text to the original text. Set line break of label:- `Truncate middle`